# Why did this person die in The Vampire Diaries?

Tags: vampire, the-vampire-diaries

In *The Vampire Diaries*, when Damon gets the spell book he needs to bring back Katherine he drags Bonnie and Grams into helping him. But once they are inside Bonnie finds out vampires can't come out. When Bonnie finds out she had to get Damon and Stefan out. So they had to do a spell. When they are done they come home, only to find **Bonnie's grandma has died.**

**Why did she die and how?**

Comment: The [wiki](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Sheila_Bennett) says she was overwhelmed by the effort needed to cast the spell; *They return home though she was greatly affect by the spell; she lies to Bonnie telling her that she will be fine. **The exhaustion finally overwhelmed her and passed away in her bedroom as Bonnie and Elena were recovering downstairs.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting magic in *The Vampire Diaries* can take a physical toll on the user's body. We see this a lot when Bonnie tries to perform magic beyond her ability, she starts to bleed out of her nose:

[image]

In this instance Gran overexerted herself to help Bonnie save her friends, in order to save Bonnie's own life. Gran not being a young woman anymore and casting magic far beyond what her and Bonnie should have attempted threatened to consume them both. If I'm remembering the scene correctly, I believe that Gran attempted to talk Bonnie out of it, but with Bonnie insistent they rescue them, Gran took the brunt of the magical burden, to keep Bonnie from killing herself.

According to [the wiki](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Bonnie_Bennett), Bonnie was insistent that her Gran help her save Elena:

> Bonnie pleads with her grandmother to help break the seal. Sheila tells her that she may not be strong enough but with Bonnie's help, maybe it will work. They both proceed to chant the spell.

Comment: My sole concern with this answer is that the only source of info is the (fan-written) wiki. That doesn't mean it's wrong, just that it's not well sourced.

Comment: @Valorum i did re-watch the scene at work, but i dont have scripts of it, but you can see in their faces their both in pain, Bonnie almost faints, nor can i make a youtube video of it sadly lol.